# Create small read-only unfocused buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer

I have a problem explaining what I need, and this is why I can't find it (probably), but I'll try my best.

I need one line of text on top of modeline, kind of a footer in the buffer. It is for displaying help, so `with-electric-help` gets very close to it except that there's an issue with focus (I can move focus back to the original window, but the key bindings will be of the help buffer - not good).

Ideally it would be just a line of text which stays on top of modeline (doesn't scroll with the buffer).

My issues with creating just a separate buffer: I don't know how to find out that the user removed focus from the buffer which was previously showing the "small buffer", so I don't know when to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

The header line sounds like it would do what you want.  It's basically the same as the mode line, except almost nothing uses it and it appears at the top of the window.

```
(setq header-line-format "some text")
```

or even fancier, you can eval things on the fly and set faces:

```
(setq header-line-format '(:eval (propertize (format "%d" (buffer-size)) 'face 'modeline-inactive)))
```